# Integrate Invision Power Board and Codeigniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, ipb

I am building a website which includes IPB.

The IPB should contain parts from the `views` (for example the header) / `models` / etc.. of the website - My question is how to integrate the website (= Codeigniter) and the IPB? where should I install the IPB? outside the `application` folder?

Answer (score 0):

- You can consider using an [Adapter Pattern](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/adapters_and_proxy_patterns).
- You should install files outside your application directory to keep it independent.
- Using the Adapter Pattern, link your controllers and models accordingly as per needs of your website requirements.
- Note that, to do this, you should also have a good insight into your IPB Application.

Comment: I'm not sure how the Adapter Pattern can help me (?).